# Como puedo Insertar una lista que dependa de otra lista en asp .net MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Lo que trato de hacer es un listado de categorías que debajo de cada categoría me liste los estudiantes que pertenecen a esa categoría.

Cambien dejare una imagen con el resultado que tengo para que puedan ver que trato de hacer y cual es el problema que tengo!

Aquí dejo el código de la vista para que se entienda mejor!

```
 <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estudiante.FirstOrDefault().Nombre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estudiante.FirstOrDefault().Apellido)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estudiante.FirstOrDefault().Direccion)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estudiante.FirstOrDefault().Activo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estudiante.FirstOrDefault().Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estudiante.FirstOrDefault().Categoria)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item2 in Model.FirstOrDefault().Estudiante)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Nombre)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Apellido)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Direccion)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Activo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Categoria.Nombre)
                </td>
```

Comment: public class CategoriasController : Controller
    {
        private DB_PracticasEntities1 db = new DB_PracticasEntities1();

        // GET: Categorias
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Categoria.ToList());
        }